# Add column to Active Record Session Store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cas

I have a rails app that implements the CAS protocol with devise to handle user authentications. And I'm having trouble implementing the single sign out because I would need to save the ticket id to delete the session when the sso request is received by the rails app.

What I don't quite understand is how to patch the Active Record Session Store in order to save the ticket number every time a new user session is generated so that I can then delete from the sessions table using that ticket number.

I'm currently using the default behavior for session store except for the following:

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.primary_key = 'session_id'
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.serializer = :json
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like doing  `session[:ticket_id] = ...` when they login, in the controller, or since it's just a model you can extend it; it's Just A Model! You can make a normal migration. And you can add callbacks.

```
class ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session
  before_create :set_ticket_id

end
```

then you can do things like `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.find_by_ticket_id session[:ticket_id]`

Comment: I thought about the `before_create` but I'm not sure how to access the ticket number from the model (it's request parameter)

Comment: I would add the ticket id to the user model, and just store the user id in the session. Or i'd use something already build, like https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable